# How to give username/password to git clone in a script, but not store credentials in .git/config

Tags: git

I am cloning a git repository in a script like this:

```
git clone https://user:password@host.com/name/.git
```

This works, but my username and my password! are now stored in the origin url in `.git/config`.

How can I prevent this, but still do this in a script (so no manual password input)?

Comment: You could probably update the origin afterwards: `git remote set-url origin https://host.com/name/.git`

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, thats possible. Thanks for the Idea. I am still hopening for a solution, that does not even temporary store the credentials.

Comment: Sure - use SSH-based auth with a key.

Comment: Is there a reason you use https instead of SSH? SSH supports keys.

Comment: I understand the question, but why are you fine with the password being stored inside the script? That's equally bad.

Comment: @mzhaase cannot use an ssh key because I am behind an http proxy

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux The password is actually given to the script through an enviornment variable. So I actually do: git clone https://username:$PASSWORD@...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The method that I use is to actually use a `git pull` instead of a clone. The script would look like:

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
git config user.email "email"
git config user.name "user"
git pull https://user:password@github.com/name/repo.git master
```

This will not store your username or password in `.git/config`. However, unless other steps are taken, the plaintext username and password will be visible while the process is running from commands that show current processes (e.g. `ps`).

As brought up in the comments, since this method is using HTTPS [you must URL-encode any special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6172719/953327) that may appear in your password as well.

One further suggestion I would make (if you can't use ssh) is to actually use an OAuth token instead of plaintext username/password as it is slightly more secure. You can generate an OAuth token from your profile settings: https://github.com/settings/tokens.

Then using that token the pull command would be

```
git pull https://$OAUTH_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@github.com/name/repo.git master
```

Comment: Unofrtantly I cannot use auth tokens. I am not using github but a private server.

Comment: Should also be noted that the username and password will be visible in, e.g., `ps` while the pull runs (at least unless you've prevented users from seeing each others' processes)

Comment: Points for oath usage.  It's exactly what I needed in production/staging/dev.

Comment: a million thanks to you buddy. wasted hours n hours n finally your answer came to resue. :thumbsup

Comment: Note that in this solution reserved characters need to be escaped. e.g. `myp@ssword` should be provided as: `myp%40ssword`

Answer (score 30):

IMO the best solution is using a custom `GIT_ASKPASS` helper and deliver the password as another environment variable. So for example, create a file `git-askpass-helper.sh` as:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec echo "$GIT_PASSWORD"
```

and then run `git clone https://username@hostname/repo` with environment variables `GIT_ASKPASS=/path/to/git-askpass-helper.sh` and `GIT_PASSWORD=nuclearlaunchcodes`.

This has the advantage that the password won't be visible in the process list too.

Comment: +1 for creative solution. This would be a little more secure than the `git pull` solution and allow you to store the plaintext password as a secret in your automated deploy tool of choice.

Comment: Did not work. Still asks for a password on `git clone`

Comment: Any way to make it work in windows? I think i saw the solution to replace the .sh file with exe, but i do not want to (Cannot stress enough) commit an exe into my repo

Comment: @PranavRaj I think you should be able to port it to a `.bat` or `.cmd` file as well but I'm not familiar with that syntax.

Comment: For anyone else looking for a cross platform solution: I used the https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki nuget package and I was able to build a .net core app which worked on both windows and linux :)

Instead of storing the password in my code, I stored it in the key vault and inside the code accessed the secret - so not saving git password as a plain text anywhere :)

Answer (score 21):

After going over **dozens** of SO posts, blogs, etc, I tried out *every* method, and this is what I came up with. It covers EVERYTHING.

## See [The Git Credentials & Private Packages Cheatsheet](https://coolaj86.com/articles/vanilla-devops-git-credentials-cheatsheet/)

These are all the ways and tools by which you can securely authenticate git to clone a repository **without an interactive password prompt**.

- SSH Public Keys

  - SSH_ASKPASS
- API Access Tokens

  - GIT_ASKPASS
  - .gitconfig insteadOf
  - .gitconfig [credential]
  - .git-credentials
  - .netrc
- Bonus: Works with Private Packages

  - node / npm package.json
  - python / pip / eggs requirements.txt
  - ruby gems Gemfile
  - golang go.mod

## Best options for no plaintext storage

From what's asked here either SSH Keys, `GIT_ASKPASS`, or `git credential store` using the OS Keychain manager might be the best choice.

Since GIT_ASKPASS is probably the least understood of the 3, I'll detail that here - and the others are in the cheatsheet.

## GIT_ASKPASS

How to create an `GIT_ASKPASS` script:

```sh
echo 'echo $MY_GIT_TOKEN' > $HOME/.git-askpass
```

How to use it:

```sh
export MY_GIT_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
export GIT_ASKPASS=$HOME/.git-askpass
git clone https://token@code.example.com/project.git
```

The script receives stdin in the form of:

```
Password for 'scheme://host.tld':
```

The script receives Git ENVs such as:

```sh
GIT_DIR=/Users/me/project/.git
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.19.0_1/libexec/git-core
GIT_PREFIX=
```

More details in the [cheatsheet](https://coolaj86.com/articles/vanilla-devops-git-credentials-cheatsheet/).

Answer (score 15):

You can enter your connection creds in your `~/.netrc` file. Something along the lines of:

```
machine host.example.net
login bart
password eatmyshorts
```

Just make sure to chmod that file to 600. If you're using windows, the following link may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password

Personally, I have a tendency to use SSH keys for auth purposes (if you are allowed, of course).

Comment: Well, this would leave my password inside ~/.netrc. I Also do not want that.

Comment: this worked for me, when GIT_ASKPASS suggestion above failed; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store your token or password somewhere safe, e.g. [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/).

Then use a bash script to map git `host` to your password store, e.g.:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# assuming "get" action from git and a config like this
# git config --global credential.helper $XDG_BIN_HOME'/git_credentials_from_pass $@'
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  if [[ "$line" =~ host=.*github.com.* ]]; then
      echo "username=your_user_name"
      echo "password=$(pass show token_github.com/your_username)"
  #else ...
  fi
done
```

Change `your_username` and `token_github.com` the way you set it up.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68602613/1803897).